# "Unable to log in with provided credentials." when trying to login my user

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm getting this error when I try to login a registered user. I read a bunch of answers in people asking the same question but none of them have solved my issue so I'm confused at to what's happening. I added some stuff to my settings like some comments said and changed some things and so far this is what I've written to no avail. Maybe some extra eyes can help. Thank you.

I'll show here my serializers:

```
user = get_user_model()

class UserRegistrationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

   username = serializers.CharField(
       required=True,
       validators=[UniqueValidator(queryset=User.objects.all(),lookup='iexact')]
   )

   email = serializers.CharField(
       required=True,
       validators=[UniqueValidator(queryset=User.objects.all(),lookup='iexact')]
   )

   password = serializers.CharField(
       required=True,
       label="Password",
       style={'input_type': 'password'}
   )

   password_2 = serializers.CharField(
       required=True,
       label="Confirm Password",
       style={'input_type': 'password'}
   )

   class Meta:
       model = User
       fields = ['username', 'email', 'password', 'password_2',]

   def validate_password(self, value):
       if len(value) < 8:
           raise serializers.ValidationError(
               "Password should be at least 8 characters long.")
       return value

   def validate_password_2(self, value):
       data = self.get_initial()
       password = data.get('password')
       if password != value:
           raise serializers.ValidationError("Passwords don't match.")
       return value

   def validate_username(self, value):
       if User.objects.filter(username=value).exists():
           raise serializers.ValidationError("Username already exists.")
       return value

   def create(self, validated_data):

       user = User(
           email=validated_data['email'],
           username=validated_data['username']
       )
       user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
       user.save()
       return user




class UserLoginSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

   username = serializers.CharField(
       required=True,
       write_only=True,
   )

   token = serializers.CharField(
       allow_blank=True,
       read_only=True
   )

   password = serializers.CharField(
       required=True,
       write_only=True,
       style={'input_type': 'password'}
   )

   class Meta(object):
       model = User
       fields = ['username', 'password', 'token']

   def validate(self, data):
       username = data.get('username', None)
       password = data.get('password', None)

       if username and password:
           user = authenticate(request=self.context.get('request'),
                               username=username, password=password)
           if not user:
               msg = 'Unable to log in with provided credentials.'
               raise serializers.ValidationError(msg, code='authorization')
       else:
           msg = "Must include username and password."
           raise serializers.ValidationError(msg, code='authorization')

       data['user'] = user
       return data
```

My views for the serializers:

```
User = get_user_model()

class UserLoginAPIView(generics.CreateAPIView):

   permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny, )
   serializer_class = serializers.UserLoginSerializer

   def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       serializer = UserLoginSerializer(data=request.data, context={'request': request})
       serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
       user = serializer.validated_data['user']
       token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
       return Response({"status": status.HTTP_200_OK, "Token": token.key})

   

class UserRegistrationAPIView(generics.CreateAPIView):

   permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny, )
   serializer_class = serializers.UserRegistrationSerializer

   def post(self, request):
       serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
       if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
           return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

       return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: What happens if you don't pass the request to `authenticate`? Just username and password. Also, have you checked from the shell? Get the user and do a `user.check_password(<your password here>)`.

Comment: @gdef_ Thank you for the comment. When i try User.objects.get() in my shell, I get this error: AttributeError: Manager isn't available; 'auth.User' has been swapped for 'backend.User'. I'm not sure if it's related or not. Also, if I take out the authenticate I get this error: Field 'id' expected a number but got <class 'backend.models.User'>.

Comment: @gdef_ I could solve the manager issue but I still only get my superuser and not the other users.